# Azure Event Hub partition numbering & Sending to specific partition

Tags: c#, azure-eventhub

I have a quick question about sending messages to a partition in an event hub in Azure.  If you have 32 partitions in an event hub what is the numbering?

Is it 0 to 31 or 1 to 32?

I'm assuming 0 to 31 but I wanted to confirm.

https://{servicebusNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{eventHubPath}/partitions/{partitionId}/messages

Answer (score 3):

Azure EventHubs `partition numbering` is from 0-X as of today (01/24/2018).

However, Microsoft Azure EventHubs `partition numbering` **SHOULD NOT** be used for sending to EventHubs. `This specific number being the partition name/identifier` - is purely an implementation detail.

Use [`EventHubClient.GetEventHubRuntimeInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient.getruntimeinformation?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventHubClient_GetRuntimeInformation) API to fetch the partitionIds list. Then use [`EventHubRuntimeInformation.PartitionIds[index]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubruntimeinformation.partitionids?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventHubRuntimeInformation_PartitionIds) to create the Sender.

This is generalization built-in to support scenarios - if the Service ever provides - capabilities like - splitting a large partition etc., and then being able to give them names after splitting like - `2-1`, `2-2` (supposing the original `partition 2` was very large and split)..

[more on Event Hubs...](https://link.medium.com/ZFqhxR8myW)

Answer (score 0):

The numbering is zero-based. Below picture shows 4 partitions of Event Hub in [Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) tool:

[image]